# Cargar .css-.js en Angular 4.4.4

Tags: css, angular

Tengo 2 proyectos de Angular que no he hecho yo, la cuestion es que se me pidio una modificacion, encontre un codigo fuente del mismo y estoy tratando de cargas estilos y js, los archivos estan asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En rojo donde quiero cargar los archivos y en azul lo que deseo cargar, el codigo esta de la siguiente manera:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>PedidosWeb</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link rel='stylesheet' href='stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css'/>
  
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='stylesheets/style.css'/>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='stylesheets/fontsIcon.css'/> 
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC9pnDdHXxMf0sI1sBQs-pLSvT5r2uAu7c&libraries=places&language=fr" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <my-app>Cargando..</my-app>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/P3WGT/inline.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/P3WGT/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/P3WGT/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/P3WGT/main.bundle.js"></script>
```

Cuando se refresca la pagina, me sale asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La URL por aquello que tenga que ver:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intente cargarlo en `.angular-cli.json` pero tampoco sirve, y quiero dejarlo como el original (el PRD) que tiene los `<link></link>` y `<script></script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tus ficheros deben de ir en `src/app/assets`. La carpeta `stylesheets` solo afecta a los componentes y al compilarse toma otra estructura. Para trabajar de manera global (que es lo que requiere `index.html` necesitas usar `src/app/assets`. Y ahí tu url sería algo como:

`<link rel='stylesheet' href='assets/css/style.css'/>`

Nótese que ´se creó una carpeta con nombre `css` para orden.

Answer (score 0):

Es una versión antigua de Angular y no sé si funcionará, pero en versiones actuales puedes poner en el archivo `angular.json` (el equivalente al `angular-cli.json` de tu versión de Angular), en la sección `assets` algo de este estilo:

```
    "assets": [
       "rutas y/o archivos que tú tengas puestos"
       {
          "glob": "*",
          "input": "stylesheets",
          "output": "./stylesheets"
       }
    ],
```

Le estás diciendo que te cargue en una ruta de salida `stylesheets` (le puedes poner la que quieras) todos los archivos que se encuentran en la ruta `stylesheets`

Y con esto debería encontrarte en tu archivo `index.html` los archivos de la carpeta `stylesheets` y cargarlos.

A ver si te funciona